# What is the meaning of 'key' in psycopg connection pooling?

Tags: python, connection-pooling, psycopg2, psycopg

I am going through [Psycopg Connections Pooling](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html) documentation, and don't understand what is the purpose of 'key' argument in getconn and putconn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perusing the source code of *psycopg2* (`lib/pool.py`) you can see that the `psycopg2.pool.AbstractConnectionPool` class has a `dict` attribute named `_used` where the connections in the pool are referenced. The `key` parameter in the `getconn` and `putconn` methods is the the key to the items in that dictionary. By default, if the value of the `key` parameter of these methods is `None` the `id` of the connection object is used as the key.

Basically the `key` parameter allows implementers of concrete connection pool classes to identify connections. For example, in the `psycopg2.pool.PersistentConnectionPool` class, a single connection is meant to be shared in a single thread, so the thread ID is used as the key.