# How does Psycopg2 handle sessions and transactions concurrency on high traffic apps?

Tags: python, database, transactions, psycopg2

I've been going through **psycopg2** documentation to understand how it handles transactions and so on and so forth.

I got that a transaction is **created on a connection level**, regardless of the cursor you use, the **session is visible to all** of them.

> **Warning** By default even a simple SELECT will start a transaction: in long-running programs, if no further action is taken, the session will remain “idle in transaction”, an undesirable condition for several reasons (locks are held by the session, tables bloat…). For long-lived scripts, either make sure to terminate a transaction as soon as possible or use an autocommit connection.

So I was wondering how a **high-traffic API** would deal with this to avoid weird situations where multiple queries are committed or rolled back because a different API request was completed and as the session is shared ... everything falls inside the same transaction.

**[Connection pools](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html)** seem to be the answer but still, the number of connections is limited so virtually you could encounter the same issue if the same connection from the pool is given to different API requests.

Is it a matter of having a pool big enough to reduce the risk of a connection being shared by 2 different processes or am I missing something on how this works?

Thanks in advance ^^ sorry for the long question.

Comment: The way these things work in general is that each request gets a connection from the pool, and a connection can only be held by one request at a time. To reduce load on the db, and the length of time for which connections are checked there may be various layers of caches between the request and the db.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb. Is this behavior something that happens by default or is being handled by psycopg2 or is it something I do need to consider while building the API? 

I guess its automatically handled, but it's still a black box for me (no clue how its internally handling this?

Comment: 1) Use `with` to have the connection close automatically. 2) Unless you use `getconn(key=some_key)` and ask for connection by key name you get a different connection on each request to the pool. 3) You can use [autocommit](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AdrianKlaver! As per your points:

1 and 3) This is an easier way to ensure the connections are closed and transactions committed after use, but it can be achieved either way if you are conscious and close/commit "manually". However, it will have no impact on the potential concurrency and transactions being shared across multiple requests issue.

On point 2 though, I understand then that a new connection is retrieved every time for each request to the pool. As you can set the max number of connections to have in the pool, do you know how it will behave in that case?

Comment: There is too much information left out of your question as to how the requests are being done to come up with anything approaching an answer. In any case the only way to really answer this is to set up realistic test cases with your setup and see for your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed connection pools are the answer, here is why:

As mentioned in [Psycopg2 pool docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html):

> getconn(key=None)
> Get a **free** connection from the pool.

The thing to highlight here is the *free* word.

Based on a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12970301/1046474) I went looking into the library to see how the connections are being retrieved from the pool:

```
def _getconn(self, key=None):
    """Get a free connection and assign it to 'key' if not None."""
    if self.closed:
        raise PoolError("connection pool is closed")
    if key is None:
        key = self._getkey()

    if key in self._used:
        return self._used[key]

    if self._pool:
        self._used[key] = conn = self._pool.pop()
        self._rused[id(conn)] = key
        return conn
    else:
        if len(self._used) == self.maxconn:
            raise PoolError("connection pool exhausted")
        return self._connect(key)
```

Psycopg2 keeps a list of the available connections and the ones being used. So, as mentioned in the comments, it indeed gives you a **free** connection. Each API request will have its own isolated transaction as they will receive a free connection each time.

More importantly, as it was the question, is that if we request for a new connection when we have the max number of conn created and all of them are in use, Psycopg2 will not give you a connection being used by another request. It will rise a PoolError. No risk of weird overlapping transaction issues happening.

**Things to consider**
Keep in mind the DB has its own limit for open connections:

> max_connections (integer)
> Determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. The default is typically 100 connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined during initdb). This parameter can only be set at server start. ([from: Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html))

If your API scales based on demand, consider setting your maxconn on the server side considering that the same 100 available will be shared between all your API instances.

Thanks to @snakecharmerb and @AdrianKlaver as their comments led me to the answer.